# Google App engine - Java Receiving Email

Tags: java

I create ticket when a mail received from customer.its working fine. I send confirmation mail to customer. if customer reply the confirmation mail, it will create comments. this is also working fine. my problem is when comments creation mail after send confirmation send many times. why its happening? confirmation comments mail is send more mail, continuously happend. if i delete the ticket only it will stop.

Comment: Reply mail receiving separate mail? my opinion, I replied conversation mail. is it receive by separately? please reply

Comment: yes my opinion is correct. if reply conversation is having two, receiving mail as two times. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: please reply how to solve conversation mail receiving duplicate? i'm awaiting your favorable reply

Comment: I think if set reply to it we be solved. please how to set reply_to in java

Comment: thanks for prompt response stackoverflow.com. I rectified my error. now working fine. thanks thanks